# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x^2} \right)^{x}$ without L'Hôpital.

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(1+\dfrac{1}{x^2} \right)^{x}$ without l'hôpital.

What I have tried:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(1+\dfrac{1}{x^2} \right)^{x} = \displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty}\left[ \left(1+\dfrac{1}{x^2} \right)^{x^2}\right]^{\frac{1}{x}}$

I would really like to say that is $e^0$, but that's probably illegal. Is there another way?

Comment: Your manipulation is actually completely fine. The answer is indeed $e^0 = 1$.

Comment: It does. I searched it, but couldn't find it anywhere. Do I delete my question?

Comment: No, leave it. It might help search engines. Btw, many other duplicates can be found, [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cleft(1%2B%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5E2%7D%20%5Cright)%5E%7Bx%7D%24&p=1).